# Is R tool compatible with apache hadoop

Tags: r, apache, hadoop, cloudera

Most of the websites have mentioned that Cloudera and hortonworks are easy to handle with hadoop. My quesiton is R tool works with apache hadoop versions??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a number of R packages and tutorials for integration with Hadoop.

Here are some installation instructions: http://www.rdatamining.com/tutorials/rhadoop

Here is a webinar on the topic: http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/free-webinars/using-r-hadoop

Comment: Revolution is not the same as base R, and unless one is connected to academia, the software is not free.